# Candy Crush Saga - Spinner wheel

Tags: candy-crush-saga

I have been playing Candy Crush Saga for many years. I play it usually to kill some time. I remember over three years ago, they implemented a spinning wheel where you can make a spin to receive some bonuses.
In that wheel, there is a field called Jack Pot.

Wheel has 7 fields and one labeled Jack Pot, totaling 8 fields.

For the last three years (almost daily) I have spun that wheel, and never received that Jack Pot. I have two friends also, who play less than I, and also they have never won that bonus.

I have contacted the support some time ago, but I was told it is a game of chance. Bad luck.

I can't have bad luck for all that time. Does anyone have any information about this?

PS. I am level 2529.

Comment: You really should consider playing another game. (3 years? No jack pot?)

Comment: That's exactly what happens to me with government election… Sad! :-)

Comment: The rotation you see is not what define what you win, there is no *physics* in this rotation what defines a win. It's a simple visualization of simple `RND()` (method returning pseudorandom value) with very low chance to trigger jackpot, which may still be low if you multiply it by 365 or even 365000. E.g. having one to million chances to win, after playing 1000 years you would still have only 30% to win **once** (in average, bad luck means less). Taking in account number of Candy Crush Saga players it's surely much less than that. Don't expect to get it any soon.

Comment: Well the chance of winning is the same every time since it does not take into account of the spins you made before. Just like the lotto, every draw is independent of the previous so the chance of winning for anyone is the same, unless you buy more numbers

Answer (score 3):

A similar question was asked about the jackpot before and my answer remains the same.

The wheel is fixed. It is not 1/8 chance because if it is then no one would complain about not hitting it after years of playing. People have won it before, you can see videos of it on youtube.

Support isn't lying to you when they say it's a game of chance. Of course it is a game of chance but what % of a chance?? I can tell you right now it is not 1/8. There is no need for a source because we have real playing time data. You played for 3 years and not hitting it once, me playing it for possibly longer than you(forgot when I started playing) and not hitting it once. The chance of hitting it is really really really low, that's all it matters but it is possible mathematically since the chance is bigger than 0. We have proof of this on youtube.

I have made it thru 3000+ levels and I spin that wheel every day just like you but still no luck. Think of it as winning the lotto, almost impossible

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to win Jackpot on Candy Crush Saga. Proof is below.

It did not say specifically what was the prize, but after the winning, it showed me a **surplus of boosters**. I think it was:

- +5 Colored Candies
- +5 Striped/Wrapped candies
- +5 Free Move boosters;
- +5 Lollipop boosters;

My estimate can be wrong as I don't recall how many I had before the winning.

I apologize for not having a screenshot tool so I had to take a photo using a camera.

Good luck winning it for yourself!

[image: Screenshot of Jackpot]